# How to install ROracle on R 4.1.3

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I am attempting to install the ROracle package in RStudio so that I may connect R to my Oracle databases. I downloaded the zip file but when I run

```
remotes::install_local("ROracle_1.3-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

I get an error :

```
ERROR: cannot find Oracle Client. Please set OCI_LIB64 to specify its location.
```

I do have Oracle Client installed on my PC. This may be an obvious answer, but my question is, how do I set OCI_LIB64 to recognize Oracle CLient's location on my PC. I am running on windows 10 and R version 4.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [installation guide](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL). It has the following steps for windows:

```
  13.Add the full path of the Instant Client to the environment variables 
     OCI_LIB64 and PATH. 

     The following steps set the variables to the PATH used in this example, 
     c:\myoreclient\instantclient_11_2. 
  1. In Windows Control Panel, select System, then click Advanced system 
     settings.
  2. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables. 
  3. Under System variables, create OCI_LIB64 if it does not already exist. 
  4. Set the value of OCI_LIB64 to c:\oreclient\instantclient_11_2. 
  5. Under System variables, edit PATH to include 
     c:\oreclient\instantclient_11_2.
```

Comment: gsalem - This worked. I ended up updating my oracle instant client (I was still using version 11, the most up to date is somewhere in version 21). I also installed the SDK package.

Comment: Note the most recent ROracle package is available directly from Oracle at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html.  The CRAN site has some issues uploading new ROracle packages.